# Vue.js: binding select boxes, but don't want to ajax all the options

Tags: vue.js, axios

Good day.  I'm using Vue.js to render an **arbitrary** number of select elements from the data in a component.

Here's sample JSON data that indicates there are two select elements, each with one or more options.

```
{
   "dropdowns":[
      {
         "cd":"UG9ydGZvbGlv",
         "formname":"sp_filter_UG9ydGZvbGlv",
         "nm":"Portfolio",
         "selected":"1a",
         "options":[
            {
               "cd":"1a",
               "val":"Option 1A"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "cd":"UHJvZHVjdCBOYW1l",
         "formname":"sp_filter_UHJvZHVjdCBOYW1l",
         "nm":"Product Name",
         "selected":"2b",
         "options":[
            {
               "cd":"2a",
               "val":"Option 2A"
            },
            {
               "cd":"2b",
               "val":"Option 2B"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Here's the template HTML:

```
<form>
   <div v-for="dropdown in dropdowns">
      <div v-if="dropdown.availableToView">
         <h4>{{dropdown.nm}}</h4>
         <select v-model="dropdown.selected" v-on:change="triggerUpdate">
            <option value="">(Make a selection)</option>
            <option v-for="option in dropdown.options" :value="option.cd">{{option.val}}</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

So far so good.

I've got the data loading and Vue is building the dropdowns.

When the user changes any select box (remember there can be an arbitrary number of them), the trigger action needs to submit ALL of the elements in the form via ajax.  It sounds like the most correct option is to bind the form fields to the underlying component data, as I've done.

My triggerUpdate looks like this:

```
methods: {
    triggerUpdate: function() {       
        axios({
                method: "post",
                url: actionURL,
                data: this.dropdowns
            })
            .then(response => (this.data = response));
    }
}
```

...but this submits the entire **dropdowns** data element, including all of the options in each select box.  It's unnecessary to send all of the options in.  I just want to send each field name along with its selected option (i.e. the "value").

I know i could serialize the whole form and make that my ajax payload.  But that seems to be making an "end run" around Vue.js.  Everyone talks about having your form fields bound to the Vue model...is it then correct to basically ignore the model when making an ajax request whose purpose is to then update the model?

I'm relatively new to Vue.js so I'd appreciate help with what I'm overlooking here.  How should I go about sending in the data from the form (a) while using proper Vue.js binding and (b) without sending extraneous data?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What about filtering all dropdowns.options.cd inside a property and on-change event that property array gets sent via axios. You might filter the data within the created lifecycle to have that loaded with your page.

Comment: Thank you for the comment..I've looked at using a derived property too..and it would work.  It just seemed a bit "hacky" to me. But completely valid nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to post only the selected values, and you store those in each `dropdown`'s `selected` property, the sensible approach seems to be just mapping it to a simple array of name/value objects.

Try this (it assumes the name of each field is the `formname` property, if it isn't you can just replace it):

```
var submitData = this.dropdowns.map((dropdown) => {
    return { name: dropdown.formname, value: dropdown.selected };
});
```

Then you send `submitData` in your ajax request.

Comment: This is pretty beautiful. Going to make it work. Thank you!